# Error: C stack usage 7969408 is too close to the limit when using fredr

Tags: r, c

I am attempting to pull every monthly time series at the state level from the FRED website using the R fredr library. I'm having issues with an error I have no context for, 'Error: C stack usage  7969408 is too close to the limit'. I'm not even sure what a stack is or what stack usage refers to. My code in its entirety is as follows:

```
library('fredr')
library('tibble')
library('plyr')

fredr_set_key("9520a1b12422146da1b8126f77b8b53b")

x <- list('al', 'ak', 'az', 'ar', 'ca', 'co', 'ct', 'de', 'fl', 'ga', 'hi', 'id',
          'il', 'in', 'ia', 'ks', 'ky', 'la', 'me', 'md', 'ma', 'mi', 'mn', 'ms',
          'mo', 'mt', 'ne', 'nv', 'nh', 'nj', 'nm', 'new york', 'nc', 'nd', 'oh',
          'ok', 'or', 'pa', 'ri', 'sc', 'sd', 'tn', 'tx', 'ut', 'vt', 'va', 'wa',
          'wv', 'wi', 'wy')

get_monthlies <- function(x){
  offset = 0
  y = fredr_tags_series(tag_names = paste(x, ';monthly'), offset = offset)
  w = fredr_tags_series(tag_names = paste(x, ';monthly'), offset = offset)
  while(nrow(w) == 1000){
    offset = offset + 1000
    w = fredr_tags_series(tag_names = paste(x, ';monthly'), offset = offset)
    y = rbind(y,w)
  }
  y$place = x
  return(y)
}


multiple_calls_monthly <- function(x){
  #y = lapply(x, function(m) multiple_calls_monthly(m)) erroneous recursion
  y = lapply(x, function(m) get_monthlies(m))
  w = ldply(y, rbind)
  return(w)
}

multiple_calls_monthly(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:

C uses a stack of data to temporarily save data. Every time a C function is called, information is pushed onto the stack; when the function is finished, it releases the data it placed onto the stack. So the stack grows and shrinks. The stack is not infinite. At some point, when there are too many functions called that did not yet finish, the stack will be exhausted. In your case, the run-time system checks if there is enough storage available before (or after) placing data onto the stack. That system determined the stack is exhausted and warned you.

Some systems, possibly your R, place huge "blobs" onto the stack, effectively making a copy of the data.

You could walk through your code to see where large data sets are used, and see if you could make those references to data sets, eliminating the need to make copies of these data sets. I am no expert there and leave that to you (or other Stack members).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the issue was that I was mistakenly recursing on multiple_calls_monthly rather than calling get_monthlies

Comment: "C uses a stack of data to temporarily save data." --> C does not specify this.  It is a common implementation though.